TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError - Signature expired: block height exceeded
This is my function code:
async sendAndConfirmTransactionWithRetry(connection: Connection, instructions: TransactionInstruction[], signer: Wallet, feePayer: Wallet = null) {

    let latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('confirmed')

    let messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: feePayer ? feePayer.publicKey : signer.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
      instructions,
    }).compileToV0Message();

    let versionedTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
    versionedTransaction.sign(feePayer ? [signer.payer, feePayer.payer] : [signer.payer]);
    console.log('fee: ', await connection.getFeeForMessage(versionedTransaction.message))

    return promiseRetry(async (retry, number) => {
      // for (let number = 1; number <= 5; number++) {
      console.log(`Attempt number ${number} to send transaction`);
      try {
        const epochInfo = await connection.getEpochInfo('confirmed')
        if (number > 1 && epochInfo.blockHeight >= latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight) {
          console.log('epochInfo:', epochInfo)
          latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('confirmed')

          messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
            payerKey: feePayer ? feePayer.publicKey : signer.publicKey,
            recentBlockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
            instructions,
          }).compileToV0Message();

          versionedTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
          versionedTransaction.sign(feePayer ? [signer.payer, feePayer.payer] : [signer.payer]);
        }
        console.log('latestBlockHash:', latestBlockHash)
        const rawTransaction = versionedTransaction.serialize()
        const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
          skipPreflight: true,
          maxRetries: 3,
          preflightCommitment: 'processed'
        });
        console.log(`Transaction Submitted: ${txid}`);

        await connection.confirmTransaction(
          {
            signature: txid,
            blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
            lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
          }
        );

        return txid
      } catch (error) {
        // console.error(`Attempt ${number} failed with error: ${error}`);
        // if (number === 5) {
        //   // Last attempt failed, throw the error
        //   throw new Error(`Transaction failed after ${number} attempts.`);
        // }
        // // Wait for 2 seconds before retrying
        // await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
        console.error('Transaction failed, retrying...', error.message);
        retry(error);
      }
    }, {
      retries: 5, // Number of retries
      factor: 2, // Exponential backoff factor
      minTimeout: 1000, // Minimum timeout between retries in milliseconds
      maxTimeout: 5000, // Maximum timeout between retries in milliseconds
    })
  }

const sourceAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(this.connection, this.wallet.payer, new PublicKey(this.usdtAddress), this.wallet.publicKey)
    const desAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(this.connection, this.wallet.payer, new PublicKey(this.usdtAddress), this.walletPayFee.publicKey)

    const feeFromApi = await this.getPriorityFee()
    console.log('feeFromApi', feeFromApi)
    
    const instructions = [
      createTransferInstruction(
        sourceAccount.address,
        desAccount.address,
        this.wallet.publicKey,
        Number(0.01) * Math.pow(10, this.usdtDecimals)
      )
    ]
    
    // Simulate the transaction to check for errors
    const computeUnits = await getSimulationComputeUnits(this.connection, instructions, this.walletPayFee.publicKey, [])
    const unitPrice = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ microLamports: feeFromApi * 20 })

    const unitLimit = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ units: Math.ceil(computeUnits * 1.5) })
    instructions.push(unitLimit)
    instructions.push(unitPrice)
    console.log('unitLimit', computeUnits * 1.5)
    console.log('unitPrice', feeFromApi * 20)

    const result = await this.sendAndConfirmTransactionWithRetry(this.connection, instructions, this.wallet, this.walletPayFee)
    console.log('result: ', result)

result is
Signature 5rJT3EC6ckgXcF9kYkMskRaKUJE4tVpjq4BMSPhG9VfuR4WGvrEu2Pe9TRkF8937Z2nRMP8gbk8KKHFh1TdWYVZi has expired: block height exceeded.


Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?

Your transactions are not landing due to congestion. The priority fees you're setting might not be enough and you might need to increase them. Additionally, it is recommended to manage the retires client side and not use the maxRetries option.
The idea is to subscribe to a transaction confirmation and then resend it if it's confirmed within a time period.
You can read more about it here
Here's you you can do it
const TX_RETRY_INTERVAL=2000;
let txSendAttempts = 1;

  try {
    console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} Subscribing to transaction confirmation`);

    confirmTransactionPromise = connection.confirmTransaction(
      {
        signature: txSignature,
        blockhash: blockhashResult.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: blockhashResult.lastValidBlockHeight,
      },
      "confirmed"
    );

    console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} Sending Transaction ${txSignature}`);
    await connection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize(), {
      skipPreflight: true,
      maxRetries: 0,
    });

    confirmedTx = null;
    while (!confirmedTx) {
      confirmedTx = await Promise.race([
        confirmTransactionPromise,
        new Promise((resolve) =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(null);
          }, TX_RETRY_INTERVAL)
        ),
      ]);
      if (confirmedTx) {
        break;
      }

      console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} Tx not confirmed after ${TX_RETRY_INTERVAL * txSendAttempts++}ms, resending`);

      await connection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize(),  
      skipPreflight: true,
        maxRetries: 0,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  if (!confirmedTx) {
    console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} Transaction failed`);
    return;
  }

  console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} Transaction successful`);
  console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} Explorer URL: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txSignature}`);


You're getting the error because the blockhash set in the transaction is getting expired. Your transaction wants to get in a block on the chain, but due to congestion is not able to. After the blockhash expires, the transaction is no longer valid and you get the error. You can read more about it in more detail here
Additionally, using an RPC provider that sends your transaction via multiple routes including a stake-weighted route will also be helpful. Also, make sure you're using a private RPC endpoint and not the public https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com, you can learn more about RPC providers here
